# Django get PK dynamically from views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a view that renders a comment form along with a template:

**views.py**

```
def news(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = Article.objects.get(pk=2)
            print(comment.post)
            comment.author = request.user.username
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, '../templates/news.html', context={"form": form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', blank=True)
    author = models.TextField()
    text = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text',)
```

In views.py, where **comment.post** is getting assigned to Article objects, I want the pk to be applied dynamically. I tried doing it in the templates, where putting {{ article.pk }} in the templates output the right pk for the Article object but I wasn't sure how I'd go about applying it to my form.

The templates look simple: Article object, below it a comment form.

The problem is simple, I want the news(request) function to dynamically apply the pk of the current Article object in order to make the comment go to the right post.

Comment: You can retrieve the `pk` with post request, just add an input field in your form that contains the news.pk as value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the path if it's unique or you can just add a hidden field and set the article pk as value:

```
<input name="post" type="hidden" value={{ article.pk }} />
```

And your form:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('text', 'post')
```

and you can access it from validated data in view.